# Split string at semicolon get second part only

Tags: c#

I have a string in the following format:

```
message:action
```

How can I parse this string and get the second part only?

The action might be different the first part will always be the same: `message:`

Is this a correct way?

```
string value="message:action";
string[] result = value.Split(':');
string action = result[1];
```

Comment: What happened as you ran it?

Comment: Why don't you just try it out and see what happens?

Comment: You may limit possible number of split parts by using  `string[] result = value.Split(new[] { ':' }, 2);`

Comment: I know it works just wanted to ask if this is a good way ... you can achieve something doing it wrong or doing it properly.

Comment: You can merge it if you only care about the second part: string action = value.Split(':')[1];

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is. Or, since the first part is always the same, you could simply use substring:

```
value.SubString(8);
```

Comment: Splitting on the ':' is safer as it is a more general solution in case something changes or there is a data error it will continue to function correctly.

Comment: You have a point, but the question states the first part was always the same. (I did say 'Or') btw, I can't type fast enough; other posts appear when I finish mine :)

Comment: NO problem - a DRY solution should always be the one of choice :-)

Answer (score 3):

That solution is fine, but it's a little more work than necessary. If you *know* that the string will always start with `"message:"`, why not just do this:

```
var action = value.Substring(8);
```

However, if the string that comes before the `:` might change, but you still only care about what comes after it, you could do this:

```
var action = value.Substring(value.IndexOf(':') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your solution will work. However, if the first part is always the same, another possibility is to use `Substring` as pswg's answer mentions.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the string will start with `message:` you can do this:

```
String value="message:action";
String result = value.Replace("message:","");
```

Comment: This won't work if "value" has more than one "attribute". Perhaps something like "message:action;priority:10"

Comment: @Areks Well he said he want the part after `message:`, he hasn't mentioned that there will be something after the `action`

Answer (score 0):

It's OK, although if you worry about there being colons in the content (e.g., "message:action:do this"):

```
string value="message:action";
string[] result = value.Split(':');
string action = value.Substring(result[0].Length);
```

(this is of course if it's not always starting with "message:")

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have self-documenting code, you can use regex (so you don't think in the future, what the heck is this code and why do I take second part).

```
string value = "message:action";
string action = Regex.Match(value, "(?<=^message:).*").Value; // will throw exception in case if someday format changes
```

Comment: [Now you have two problems](http://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/) :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding one more answer for legibility.  There are several correct answers in the thread so far.

Just to offer a very readable alternative at very little cost of performance consider the following:

```
    string value = "message:action";
    string action = value.Split(':').Skip(1);
```